# Override an action on Sales Order Screen

Tags: acumatica

I am currently doing a customization where I have to override 'create shipment' action on SalesOrder screen in order to change the location ID with customized attributes value and save it in SOShipLine table. Can anyone please guide me how to start with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one is a special case because Create Shipment is an Automation. This Automation calls the function "CreateShipment" within the SOShipmentEntry page. To add a customization to this, all you need to do is override this function in the SOShipmentEntry page. A general function override is done like this:

```
public delegate void CreateShipmentDelegate(SOOrder order, int? SiteID, DateTime? ShipDate, bool? useOptimalShipDate, string operation, DocumentList<SOShipment> list);
[PXOverride]
public virtual void CreateShipment(SOOrder order, int? SiteID, DateTime? ShipDate, bool? useOptimalShipDate, string operation, DocumentList<SOShipment> list, CreateShipmentDelegate baseMethod)
{
    //Code before base call
    baseMethod(order, SiteID, ShipDate, useOptimalShipDate, operation, list);
    //Code after base call
}
```